# Can I port Xamarin.Android to Xamarin.ios application?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

if i like to create a new project in Xamarin Studio that target two platform Android and iOS i create new solution --> android App or Cross-platform App ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two options: *Xamarin Forms* or *Native Cross Platform* ('Single View App' in the template chooser).

*Xamarin Forms* is most useful for prototyping and data-entry apps with limited visual requirements. With the native option, on the other hand, you're completely free to create any app you'd like.

To create a new solution, use File -> New Solution -> Cross Platform -> App:

[image]

'Blank Xamarin.Forms App' will give you just that, while 'Simple View App' will give you a near-blank native cross-platform app.

To learn more on the specifics of cross platform coding with Xamarin, you might want learn more about [native](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/) and/or [Forms](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/) cross-platform development at the Xamarin Docs.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-platform App will create a Xamarin.Forms application.  Xamarin.Forms will enabled you to write UI code a single time for multiple platforms.  http://xamarin.com/forms

Otherwise you can create individual Xamarin.Platform apps for Android / iOS and use common business logic in a separate library project that they both reference.